# Why is there a white space that shows on my app when I load it on my phone

Tags: android, android-layout

As the title states, I have a white space that loads to the right of my app when I load it on my phone. When I load it on the emulator, there isn't a white space. Is it just my phone or is there some type of error in my programming? Maybe too much padding or something.

This is the only code I have touched so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/widget34"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="337dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="@drawable/zombie"
android:layout_below="@+id/widget33" >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget35"
android:layout_width="308dp"
android:layout_height="352dp" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/widget37"
android:layout_width="148dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/widget36"
android:layout_width="148dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/widget43"
android:layout_width="148dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/widget42"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/widget42"
android:layout_width="148dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_below="@+id/widget40"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/widget40"
android:layout_width="148dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/widget41"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/widget41"
android:layout_width="148dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_below="@+id/widget39"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/widget39"
android:layout_width="148dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/widget38"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/widget38"
android:layout_width="148dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/widget37"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/hole"
android:text="@string/button_shot" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget33"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="94dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@drawable/twdd"
android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hard to tell with no screenshots, code, layouts, etc...

Comment: I can't include any pictures apparently since, my rep isn't high enough....

Comment: How about the layout code? You gave us *no* information to go on to start with, so just about anything else would help.

Comment: "to the right of my app".  What does this mean?

Comment: @Geobits bare with my I'm new to stackoverflow haha

Comment: to the right of the app means the entire right border seems to have white space

Comment: Of your main screen?  If so, please post the layout for it.

Comment: I just posted the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both children (the `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout`) of the main `RelativeLayout` are set to width 320dp. They're also set to align left. If your screen is larger than 320dp, the rest of the screen will be blank.

If you want them to stretch to the full width, try setting `layout_width="match_parent"`. In general, you should try to avoid hardcoding element sizes. This will help things look better on multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I over looked that. Even the most simple things can change a lot. I appreciate the help.